Ant Design CSS file was not loaded properly on my localhost
I am currently using Ant Design v5 and React v18 for my project.
Whenever I made changes to the code file and the page got auto re-render or I refreshed (by clicking F5) on the current page, the CSS files for my node_modules went missing. When I clicked back and returned to the same page, the CSS styles were back to normal again. Has anyone encountered the same issue?
Here is the sample file

Try to run it on localhost and edit the file a few times, the CSS file might go missing in the process of re-rendering.

I've tried to manually import antd.css into my project, but Ant Design v5 does not require this step anymore. Tried installing react-refresh as well, but it does not work.
